# How to apply event on list of object ? (IEnumrable OR IList)

Tags: c#

```
public class ClassA
{
  public string Name{get;set;}
  //my other attributes and code here
}
public class ClassAList: IList<ClassA>
{

        public event EventHandler FilterButtonClicked;
        private void OnFilterButtonClick()
        {
            if (FilterButtonClicked != null)
            {
                FilterButtonClicked(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
}
```

I want **FilterButtonClicked** to register for each of list object of **ClassA**
(**don't want to register individual event handler for ClassA**). How i can achieve like this.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Another solution is using pub/sub, or some kind of decoupled messages.

Either way (and i'm not quite sure what you are doing), there has to be some segway from the child to the parent.

**Original**

There is no magic bullet here and several possible solutions.

Since your are implementing `Ilist` (i know you dont want to have to do this). However, the simplest approach might be just to bite the bulled and implement

**Given**

```
 public class ClassA
 {
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public event EventHandler FilterButtonClicked;
    private void OnFilterButtonClick()
    {
       FilterButtonClicked?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
 }
```

**Implement**

```
public void Add(ClassA item)
{
   item.FilterButtonClicked += FilterButtonClicked;
}

public void Clear()
{
   foreach (var item in this)
   {
      item.FilterButtonClicked -= FilterButtonClicked; 
   }
}

public bool Remove(ClassA item)
{
   item.FilterButtonClicked -= FilterButtonClicked; 
}

...

// and anything else you can think of
```

Note : Obviously check for nulls or there be dragons

Comment: that's well said !. But i need solution for not registering event for individual ClassA object. Code where i using this class always get list of objects & i don't want to register event for individual. I wan't something that register click on all enumerable elements and click give me parameter which tells me which element i clicked from list

Comment: @ronak in the `Add` method you can pass reference to the `ClassAList` instance, so when it is clicked, `ClassA` calls `this.classAList.OnFilterButtonClicked(this, ...)`